# Cannot properly include header file in executable file via CMake

Tags: c, cmake, build, include

I'm trying to run a project with such structure:

[image]

I have this CMake code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(Random C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(Main usage.c include/random.h source/random.c)

include_directories(include)
```

And I have this error in random.c:

[image]

BUT I don't have it in usage.c:

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: Your editor/IDE does not know that `"include/random.h"` in "random.c" is relative to the parent of the directory containing "random.c" rather than relative to the directory containing "random.c". Perhaps there is some setting in your editor/IDE to let it know.

Comment: If you add folder `include` to include folders, you should remove `include` from the include directive. Otherwise you try to include file `include/include/random.h`

Comment: @IanAbbott
@Gerhardh
Okay, that fixed the compiler error, but now I'm trying to build a library and terminal says:
`random.c:1:10: fatal error: 'random.h' file not found`
What can it be?

Comment: a) I personally prefer attaching the include directory information to a target directly b) you need to choose the correct combination of include dir and `#include` instruction; use `#include "random.h"` and `target_include_directories(Main PRIVATE include)` or `#include "include/random.h"` and `target_include_directories(Main PRIVATE .)`. in the former case you should adjust usage.c too.

Comment: @fabian okay, I see the problem, but my building library issue didn't disappear. The terminal still says that `include/random.h` can not be found in `random.c`

Comment: Is there more info in the error message? For some build systems the error message mentions the command used to compile the source file causing the issue. Which compiler/cmake generator are you using btw?

Comment: @fabian here is the [error](https://ibb.co/vzs6Cp8) and commands I use. I use gcc.

Comment: Wait... Do you manually enter the compiler commands? I'd expect the build process including the cmake configuration to look something like this: `mkdir build` `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -S . -B build` `cmake --build build`; CMake is used to generate e.g. a make file project that contains the appropriate logic for building the project. It does not change the directories available to gcc when used via command line. The last step of course could be replaced with a generator specific way of triggering the build, e.g. `cd build` `make all` for unix makefiles...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233806/discussion-between-aleksandr-novik-and-fabian).

Comment: Okay, I solve this issue... Turns out that when I used gcc command to compile, it thought that random.h was in the same folder as random.c. Had to just move them both into one folder.